# LookAndFeel changed after Build

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jar, build

I changed the LookAndFeel in my programm to "windows".
After Clean and Build, I run the .jar File, but the LookAndFeel was changed. 
When i compile the programm in Netbeans, my selected "windows" LookAndFeel works fine.

Wheres the problem? Did any library miss?

Greetings from Germany,
Patrick

```
public class main{
final private static String lookAndFeel = "Windows";
public static String getLookAndFeel(){
return lookAndFeel;}
[...]
}
```

at my frame-class:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
main ref = new main();
String lookAndFeel = ref.getLookAndFeel;
try{
for(javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()){
if(lookAndFeel.equals(info.getName())){
javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
break;
}}}catch[...]
```

[image: left the netbeans compiled version, right the cmd-jar version]

Comment: Are you sure that your jar was rebuilt?

Comment: Yes, i had to test more things with my jpa connection after build. So i must clean and build every 30 seconds :D ._.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. May be you are doing mistake at some other side. Here is an example to help you out.

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class LookAndFeel {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        String lookAndFeel = "Windows";
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if (lookAndFeel.equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            System.out.println("ERROR : " + ex);
        }

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame("TESTING");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setSize(500, 300);
                f.setLayout(new java.awt.FlowLayout());
                f.add(new JButton("Click ME"));
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I run this on my PC in Netbeans and also through CMD and it is working fine.
After `Clean and Build` you will get a .jar file in `dist` directory of your project.

in cmd after reaching the `dist` directory write following command.

```
java -jar MyProject.jar
```

Where `MyProject` is the name of project I created.
Here is the output I get in each case on my PC :

[image]

Comment: I hope it will help you. @P4Zi

Comment: this is nearly the same code. i have other frame-content. :(

Comment: May be it is because you might be using different JVM. I mean you might have 2 different jdk versions on your PC and you had set netbeans on one and using another on cmd. check the class path of your cmd. may be it will work this way.@P4Zi

Answer (score 0):

When i try to set the LookAndFeel directly with this code:

```
javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel);
```

surrounded with try-catch, netbeans gives an syntax error and said:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol: class windows
location: package com.sun.java.swing.plaf
```

so the LaF wasn't found? Is that the fault?

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

jeah, now, it works fine.

i create a file named "swing.properties" in the directory "c:\program files\java\jre\lib\"
with the text

```
swing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel
```

now, the LookAndFeel has the right theme :) :) thanks for your answers!